# Do I get more reputation from keeping a majority species happy?

Tags: against-the-storm

My settlements often end up very specialised. For example, my last settlement had about 70% humans.

When it comes to reputation gain from resolve, would making the humans happy give more reputation than keeping the single harpy above the threshold? If not, am I better off investing in those minorities since I'd need far less to keep one harpy happy than a large number of humans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rate is based on population. This means that yes, keeping more populous species happy gives faster reputation. This screenshot shows the extreme- a single happy harpy earns 0.01 reputation/minute.
[image: Happy Harpy]
This would take 100 minutes- approximately 10 in game years- to earn a single reputation point.